# How to deal with multiple text-domain?

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, wordpress-theming, po, mo

I am talking about Wordpress localization/internationalization.

I have a two templates done by third party. And they made them child templates of twentyten. Seemingly they kept the template files with internationalized strings with the text-domain as `'twentyten'`.
Now that I have prepared the two sites for bilingual English/Arabic ready. I found that I need an unique text domain to be used. I have used the site specific keywords.

While generating the .po file I found that all the `_e(), __(), _x(), _n()` function contents got merged into the .po file but as my functions.php contains one text-domain with the function `load_theme_textdomain`. Only those strings having this text domain shows translated. Others appear in English.

I want to hear from experienced developers. How do they co-exist this sort of scenario. I am now converting all the text-domains into one so that my site just looks good. But am I just working extra or there were easy or modularized way of doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might manage child's theme translated strings using [`load_child_theme_text_domain()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_child_theme_textdomain). It is the right way for translating on a parent-child theme scenario. This way you can use strings from parent for some uses, and strings from childs for the others.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a detailed answer for maintaining the .po and .mo for parent and child themes together.